# How to run PPT file in Android

Tags: android

How can I run PowerPoint (.ppt) file in Android programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need either implement your own Activity, whish is able to read ppt files, or use a thirdparty application to do it. In that case you need to know the particular action to set to the intent in order to launch it. As I know, quick office can read ppt files.

Comment: i would like to create my own activity... how can i do this can u direct me to some tutorial or link??

Comment: Hi, I need to open ppt file in my app, I tried "pptviewer" demo app available on github, it was working in mobile device but its not properly working on android tv, I need it for android tv, do you have any idea to open ppt file in android tv